# Laravel same authorization for update and edit method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I would like to keep my authorization as DRY as possibile.
Currently for my update method I am using Laravel 5 FormRequest.

Example:

```
/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    $commentId = $this->route('comment');

    return Comment::where('id', $commentId)
                  ->where('user_id', Auth::id())->exists();
}
```

The problem is that this gets triggered just for update method:

```
 /**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function update(UpdateRequest $request, $id)
{
         // ...
}
```

How can I use the same authorize logic for edit method?

Otherwise everyone can just type:

```
/resources/ID/edit
           ^
           not allowed
```

Only the owner should see that page, not everyone

Note I can't add that same `UpdateForm` to the edit method, because otherwise validation could be triggered too

```
 /**
 * Show edit form for the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function edit(UpdateRequest $request, $id)
{
         // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have something called middleware in laravel 5.
You can use it in the route so that it gets executed before the action has been called.
I think for what you need you will have to create your own middleware.

http://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware

After you created one you have to tell laravel to use the middleware and then add it to your route like so

```
route::get('test', ['middleware' => 'yourmiddleware', 'uses' => 'yourController@index']);
```

Comment: so why there is this RequestForm class with authorize method if everyone says use middle for auth?

Comment: I think for extra security. The requestform authorization will only get triggerd at a request. But when you will go to /resources/edit/1 then its not the same as an post request so in that case you should use middleware to make sure only the people who should see it can see it.